# How to change a users shell in passed with script

Tags: bash, scripting, sed

I am writing a bash script to change a users shell in passwd and have it be called from Rundeck.  I have tried awk but I like the inline editing of sed.  But I am not sure what shell the user had to compare and replace.  So I need to search the passwd file for the username and then change the shell.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `chsh` and don't try to be too clever.

```
chsh -s /bin/bash sven
```

Comment: Problem is that the systems are NIS and the passwd and shadow as well as the maps are in a SRC directory under /var/yp